# UISwitch detailed text underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

[image: Text not underneath]

I want to be able to put the descriptive text underneath the label. Below is the code I have thus far:

```
UISwitch *toggle = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Remote Execution";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Remote execution will permit registered devices to execute tests without manually starting them";
    [cell addSubview:toggle];
    cell.accessoryView = toggle;
    [cell.detailTextLabel setAlpha:1.0];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` instead of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: That worked, but my message seems to long for 1 line underneath. Is there any way I can have it split over 2 lines underneath? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same message for every cell? Will it sometimes be only 1 line and sometimes 2 lines? Or even 3 lines? What about if the device is rotated to landscape orientation? Best bet would be to create a custom cell and use auto-layout for dynamic height cells.

Comment: I just set         cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;